# Clicking on area near text loads and displays users' personal information!

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, moderator-tools, pii

In the user's mod dashboard page I was selecting some text, but I accidentally clicked on or around the area near "(access to PII is logged)" and it loaded the user's PII when I didn't expect it to since it wasn't a link:

[image]

Win 10, Chrome v80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you for finding this. The link should be more precise now.